# where to add custom header code in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

Below is the code & this is the [image](http://chrisspooner.com/themes/portfolio/) that I want to add to the header (logo in center, 2 nav menus on each side of logo). 
[Here](http://www.p-ng.com/sample-page/) is the page where I want the centered logo & nav, where would you put the html code as I am not quite sure where it goes.
Any suggestions greatly appreciated

```
 #logo { 
    background:url(images/tigerPawsLogo87x87.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 87px 87px;
     width: 87px;
     height: 87px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 20px;
     left: 460px;
}

header {
        width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 40px 30px 37px 0;
}

nav li:nth-child(2) {
    padding-right: 20px;
}

nav li:nth-child(3) {
    padding-left: 20px;
}  

<header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>Catalogue</li>
                <li>Forum</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="logo"></div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code seems totally fine . just increase your padding-left of nav li:nth-child(3) according to size of your logo .

```
<style>
#logo { 
    background:url(http://chrisspooner.com/themes/portfolio/wp-content/themes/portfolio/images/logo.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 87px 87px;
     width: 87px;
     height: 87px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 20px;
     left: 460px;
}

header {
        width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 40px 30px 37px 0;
}

nav li:nth-child(2) {
    padding-right: 20px;
}

nav li:nth-child(3) {
    padding-left: 170px;
}  
</style>
<header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>Catalogue</li>
                <li>Forum</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="logo"></div>
</header>
```

Comment: haven't written the above ul, li html code onto my page as I am not sure where to put the ul,li element, would it be a html or php thing. this is for  a wordpress website